# Knowing that $b\leq\frac{a}{1-a}$ and $a<0.01$ show that $b \leq 1.01a$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods

I've been solving a problem in numerical analysis and to finish one of the exercises I need the following result.

Knowing that $b\leq\frac{a}{1-a}$ and $a<0.01$ show that $b \leq 1.01a$.

Now I think that this might be BS, but everything that led up to this point seems proper to me, so maybe I'm just wrong.

I tried the following string of inequalities:

$b \leq \frac{a}{1-a} \leq \frac{a}{1-0.01}=1.(01)a $ but that leaves the possibility that $b=1.0101a$ for example and that goes against what I'm trying to prove...

Comment: If $b$ has its maximal allowed value, that translates to $\frac{1}{1-a} \leqslant 1.01 \iff 1 \leqslant 1.01 - 1.01a \iff 1.01a \leqslant 0.01 \iff a \leqslant \frac{0.01}{1.01}$. That's a stricter requirement than you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint aassuming $\;a>0\;$ :

$$\frac a{1-a}<\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)a\iff \frac1{1-a}<\frac{101}{100}\iff 1-a>\frac{100}{101}\iff a<\frac1{101}\left(<\frac1{100}\right)$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how does that help me...

Comment: You **really** don't know, @ArekKrawczyk ?? Common, check, write along and think again.

Comment: Okay $\frac{1}{1-a}<\frac{1}{(1-\frac{1}{101})}=1.01$, but maybe because I'm freakishly tired right now I don't see how what I know about $a$ coupled with the fact that $a>0$ (what I forgot to mention) implies that $\frac a{1-a}<\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)a$.

Comment: @ArekKrawczyk:$$\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)a=1.01 a$$so $$\;b<\frac a{1-a}<\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)a\iff...a<\frac1{100}=0.01$$